# Azure DevOps, what are the default role assignments for the Resource Group?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure DevOps release pipeline which deploys a resource group. I have switched the service connection that is assigned to the Create Resource Group task to a different service principal, and now deploying the resource group (after deleting it) succeeds, but I can no longer see it in the portal. Previously, the RG made me a Contributor implicitly without me having to do anything. I am the owner of the release pipeline.

Why does changing the service principal that deploys the resource group give the resource group a different set of role assignments and how do I control the set of role assignments applied to the resource group **when it is created** so that I am made an Owner? I don't inherit any Owner permissions from the susbcription because I'm not an admin user, any permissions I have - which I still have against an identical resource group - were assigned directly to the RG on its creation, but I can't see how that happens.

Comment: What does the `Why has the set of permissions changed` mean? Based my understanding, it is not related to Azure Devops, it is depended on your service principal. If you want to see the resource group, please make sure  that you are using the corresponding subscription on the Azure portal.

Comment: @TomSun I thought I explained this in the question but I'll try to clarify: Creating the resource group with one service principal allows me to see it, with a different one doesn't, and I can't see what's different about them. In fact, I can't see how it knows to assign me as Contributor to the RG at all. I haven't changed anything other than the service connection that the Create Resource Group task runs under.

Comment: `haven't changed anything other than the service connection`. Whether you have permission to create resource group is depended on your service connection (service principle). You could assign the [roles and permissions for service principal on the azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

Comment: @TomSun that's not what I'm asking. Both SPs have permission to create the resource group. However one of them assigns a role that makes me Owner, and the other doesn't. I'm asking why this would be different between the two SPs.

Comment: can you provide any evidence that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have enough permissions. it doesnt have to do anything with Azure Devops. Azure Devops doesnt assign any permissions to the created resource group to the pipeline owner (or anybody else).

one reason why that might happen - you filtered out the subscription the resource group is in. (like tom mentioned in the comment)

Comment: I thought I explained this in the question but I'll try to clarify: Creating the resource group with one service principal allows me to see it, with a different one doesn't, and I can't see what's different about them. In fact, I can't see how it knows to assign me as Contributor to the RG at all. I haven't changed anything other than the service connection that the Create Resource Group task runs under. If devOps doesn't assign that role, what does?

Comment: nothing. its probably in a different subscription or something like that.

Comment: Nope. That's not the answer.

Comment: yeah sure, 2 people tell you the same thing, but you are the smartest kid around. why do you ask the question if you know the answer?

Comment: Guesses aren't answers. If you don't know, you're not helpful.

Comment: thats not a guess, i know azure devops doesnt assign any permissions to the owner of the pipeline when creating a resource group. why you cant see the resource group? i have no idea. there can be many reasons for that